# Two commands SQL

Tags: c#, sql, .net, ms-access

I have a sql command:

```
connection.Open();
OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
command.Connection = connection;
command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO guestreg(g_name,g_surname,g_company,g_ad,g_dd,g_amountofdays,g_na,g_room,g_rate,g_totalrate,g_info,u_added,u_timeadded,g_status) VALUES('" + gname + "','" + gsurname + "','" + gcompany + "','" + this.dateTimePicker1.Text + "','" + this.dateTimePicker2.Text + "','" + days + "','" + gna + "','" + groom + "','" + grate + "','" + total + "','" + ginfo + "','" + label2.Text + "','" + dateTimePicker3.Value + "','"+g_status+"')";
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
MessageBox.Show("Reservation completed! Thank you, "+label2.Text+"!");
connection.Close();
```

I would like to know, I have second table in database and would like to add **some** values (from previous code) to the second table.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Side notes: 1) Do not use string concatenation. Use parameterized sql instead. See also [Best Practices - Executing Sql Statements](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/.net/3589/ado-net/14261/best-practices-executing-sql-statements). 2) wrap your disposables (like OleDbConnection) in `using` blocks.

Comment: You need to clarify what exactly you want us to help you with. Do you mean to ask how you can execute 2 SQL non-query statements with just one `command.ExecuteNonQuery()`?

Comment: @Vikhram, yes. Example: second command: Insert into table2 values ('"+value1+"').

Comment: @Igor , I am sorry Mr. Igor, I am yound developer with low experience, didn't get your message at all.. :(

Comment: How is guestreg related to table2? What values specifically do you want to insert?  Can you use a stored procedure instead of inline SQL?

Comment: ouch!! sql injection time! :o

Comment: Just add another `command.CommandText` and `command.ExecuteNonQuery();` under the last `command.ExecuteNonQuery();`

Comment: @Juanche thanks a lot! Will check in a minute!

JoshStevens, it's just a home task for me ;D